# Bilingual image(containing text) Detection

Tags: java, opencv, tesseract

I have several image containing text on which i want to perform OCR but the problem is some images are bilingual containing English and Arabic text and some are pure english. how can i detect those bilingual page? I want only english OCR.

Comment: Mind to please provide what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

I did fairly extensive research on OCR for a work project a while back and came across [Tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_(software)).  This, at the time at least, appeared to be the best OCR technology.  I came across another post and someone said there's an API for it.  According to the wiki article in the link above this has multi-lingual support.
[Here's a Java library.](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/)